# Computing the expectation of a Tricky R.V. (Brought form Neuroscience).

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I need to compute $\Bbb{E}(\tau^{X} \ \Bbb{1}_{\{\tau^{X}<+\infty\}})$ where:

$1) $ $\tau^y$ is a r.v. representing the time spent by a particle until it "jumps", ( $ y \in R_{\geq 0} $ is the starting position of the particle ). Its law is given by

$$ P(\tau^y > t)= e^{y(e^{-t}-1)}$$ Observe that $ P(\tau^y =+\infty ) = e^{-y}$
. I've also computed (for other purposes,but I think it may help) the law and expectation of $\hat{\tau}^y:=\tau^y \Bbb{1}_{\{\tau^{y}<+\infty\}} $:
$$P(\hat{\tau}^y>t)=e^{-y}(e^{ye^{-t}}-1)\ ;\ \Bbb{E}(\hat{\tau}^y)=e^{-y}\int_0^y\frac{e^s-1}{s}ds $$
$2)$ $ X $ is a R.V. with values in $R_{\geq 0} $ with 
$$ F_X(a) = \begin{cases}
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ if\ \ a<0\\
e^{-2}\ \ \ \ \ if\ \ a\in[0,1]\\
e^{2(a-2)}\ \ \ if\ \ a\in(1,2)\\
1 \ \ \ \ \ \ if\ \ a\geq 2
\end{cases} $$

Note that $P(X=0)=e^{-2}$, so it has an atom in $0$

I thought about conditional expectation, conditioning on $X$ , but I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: The result is $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^s-1}su(s)ds,$$ with $$u(s)=E(e^{-X}\mathbf 1_{X>s})=\int_1^2e^{-x}2e^{2x-4}\mathbf 1_{x>s}dx=2e^{-4}\int_1^2e^x\mathbf 1_{x>s}dx.$$ Thus, for $s>2$, $u(s)=0$, for $1<s<2$, $u(s)=2e^{-4}(e^2-e^s)$, and, for $0<s<1$, $u(s)=2e^{-4}(e^2-e)$.

Answer (score 0):

@Did

A few questions about your answer:

1) Which property did you use to get that result? Could you lend me useful bibliography  where that property appears?

2) When computing $u(s)$ did you "compute" the "density" of $X$ ? ( I put the "" because I'm not sure it DO have density, since $F_X$ has a jump at 0; and also I'm wondering if a minus is missing .